# CSS centering multiple images in rows (pyramid formation)

Tags: css, html, image

http://jsfiddle.net/XKL6E/

How can I centre these images so they form a pyramid (overlapping each other halfway)?

Comment: Is JavaScript ok, or pure CSS only?  And which frameworks are you using?

Comment: I wasn't intending to use JS, but will if it's the only option. I'm not using a framework to speak of (unless I've misunderstood).

Answer (score 2):

If you don't care to support IE7, you can use `display: inline-block` instead of `float: left` and just center the whole chunk: http://jsfiddle.net/XKL6E/16/

Comment: You can use `SPAN` instead of `DIV` and get the same effect.  Plus it works on IE7.  http://jsfiddle.net/XKL6E/21/

Comment: @Blener, just a tip about the fiddles, you don't have to hit update to run it.  I'm sure those folks will appreciate the extra room in their databases :)

Comment: @FakeRainBrigand how come the inline-block works in IE7 when you use span?

Comment: @ptriek, the IE team implemented `inline-block` for IE7, **but** it only worked on elements that were naturally `inline`.

Comment: @FakeRainBrigand: I'm too lazy to log into my account, so every time anybody saves without an account, the save attaches to the same base URL.

Comment: @FakeRainBrigand: IE7 doesn't support `inline-block`. You have to add hacky CSS styles that make it *seem* like IE7 supports it.

Comment: @FakeRainBrigand thanks, didn't know that. so - that makes your solution the best, post it.

Comment: @Blender, I'm to lazy to make an account!  But if you just press `Run`, when testing, it doesn't save as a revision.  It's like Run for testing, Update for release/deploy.  [See this.](http://doc.jsfiddle.net/basic/introduction.html#result-without-save "jsfiddle documentation")

Comment: @FakeRainBrigand: I am saying that I did not press the save button 20 times. If you press the save button, it'll append to the *exact same URL* as mine.

Answer (score 2):

Add display:inline-block to .empty-button, and text-align:center to .button_row:

http://jsfiddle.net/XKL6E/14/

Answer (score 2):

If you change all of the buttons to `span` elements instead of `div`, you can apply the `display: inline-block` to them.

Credit to **@Blender** for the `inline-block` idea and the original version of this fiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/XKL6E/21/

*Edit:*

I forgot to mention, the difference between `inline-block` on a `div` and a `span` element is IE7 support.  Articles like [this one](http://www.brunildo.org/test/InlineBlockLayout.html) give all sorts of hacky ways to make this work.  In the case of `div` elements, substituting `span` is good enough.

Answer (score 0):

Using fixed width divs and centring them automatically with

```
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
```

The fixed width is dependant on the width of the images. If the image width is always the same, which I assume in your case is, you can multiply the width by an integer ( use jQuery .css(attr,value) selector ).

Comment: the answer above ( @Blender ) is much easier though :)